# How to convert postfix expression in the form of a string into infix in c++ without using parenthesis?

Tags: string, algorithm, expression-trees, postfix-notation, infix-notation

There is a postfix expression in the form of string for e.g:  ab+cd+* , so the output should be a * c + a * d + b * c + b * d  (as we cannot write (a+b)*(c+d) because parenthesis are not allowed.)

Comment: Have you tried something? Btw, you can first do with parenthesis and then open them.

Comment: For cases like `a-(b-c)` and `d/(e/f)`, invert the operation to get `a-b+c` and `d/e*f`. For cases like `x*(y+z)`, use the distributive laws.

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych yes..i am trying to solve by making an expression tree from postfix and expanding expressions by bottom up manner by calling recursively on left and right subtree and combining the result into a string. I think this should work.

Comment: @Gassa thanks, that helped.